# как вытащить цифру из скобок python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, python-3.7

есть код ии:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# +temp, -temp, Has Water, Magnsphere, Sun Power, G
X = np.array([
    [56.7, 89.2, 1, 1, 1, 1], #Earth
    [1.68, 80, 1, 1, 1.2, 1.88], #Kepler-452b
    [35, 153, 1, 0, 1, 0.378], #Mars
    [35700, 21, 0, 0, 1, 2.535], #Jupiter
    [0.85, 150, 1, 0.5, 0.0412, 1.1], #kepler-186f
])
y = np.array([
    [1], #Earth
    [0.9], #Kepler-452b
    [0.05], #Mars
    [0], #Jupiter
    [0.08] #kepler-186f
])

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
model.compile(
    loss="mse",
    optimizer="adam",
    metrics=["mse", "mae"]
)

model.fit(
    X, 
    y, 
    epochs=1000,
    batch_size=1000, 
    verbose=0
)

test = np.array([
    [35, 153, 1, 0, 1, 0.378]
])

model.evaluate(X, y, verbose=0)
prediction = model.predict(test)
print(np.floor(prediction*100))

input("Press ENTER to exit...")
```

в ответе после запуска он выдаёт число в квадратных скобочках вот так:

```
[[5.]]
```

как от них избавиться

Comment: Вы понимаете, что означают эти скобки?

Comment: я так понимаю это массив либо список

Comment: Да, это двумерный список.

Comment: Как можно решать задачи ML без знания основ языка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я всё понял и разобрался:

```
prediction[0][0]
```